# jquery accordion open a section

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm trying to implement a state-saving accordion menu...

So far I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#accordionMenu").accordion({
        alwaysOpen: false,
        animated: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        icons: false,
        navigation: true
    });
        var toOpen = <%= MySessionInfo.Current.MyMenu %>;
        if(toOpen != -1){
            alert("it should open: " +toOpen);
            $("#accordionMenu").accordion("active", toOpen);
            alert("active is : " + $("#accordionMenu").accordion("option", "active"));
        }

        $("#accordionMenu").click(function (){
            var activate = $("#accordionMenu").accordion("option", "active");
            if (activate != false) {
                $.getJSON("/Account/SetMenu", { CurrentMenu: activate }, function (j) {});
            }
        });
    });
```

It sets the correct index and it shows the right message "it should open X", where X is the expected value.
However, it doesn't keeps open that section and after setting the "active" value, the "active is: Y" shows "false" all the time.

what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

You got a typo. It should be

```
$('...').accordion('activate', index);
```

Found at http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#method-activate

Answer (score 1):

You should do either:

```
$("#accordionMenu").accordion({active:toOpen});
```

or

```
$("#accordionMenu").accordion("activate", toOpen);
```